# What is difference between Address Register (AR) and Program Counter register (PC)?

Tags: cpu-architecture

PC stores the address of next instruction, and AR stores the address of the memory.
now the question is, why we need to have AR when we know the next instruction ?!

Comment: for loads/stores.

Answer (score 0):

The memory address register (MAR) tells the processor the address in memory (RAM or cache) that the data will be loaded from or written to. It is absolutely necessary for any load or store operation (in use with the memory data register (MDR) which is used to store the data that is read/written).